# SSIS Simple Package all Microsoft source and destination fails on data types

Tags: ssis

New Data Flow Task, steps:

1. drag Excel source onto surface
2. point to a 2019 Excel .xlsx file with a named range
3. select the named range in name of the sheet
4. verify that it is seeing the data correctly
5. drag an SQL Server destination onto the surface
6. connect the Excel data source output (green) to the SQL Server destination
7. select my server and database in the destination
8. use *New* in the *Use a Table or View* and let the editor create the destination table

There is a red x in the destination.
There is one column formatted date and three formatted time in the Excel spreadsheet.
The errors are that these cannot be converted from DT_DATE to DT_DBTIMESTAMP.
I have researched this and tried all kinds of things to get these to work to no avail.

The real frustration is Excel is a Microsoft product, [SSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) is a Microsoft product, and SQL Server is a Microsoft product.  I have let SSIS *create* the table in SQL Server and decide on the SSIS type to use from Excel, and it is getting it so wrong on such an easy task.

I do understand that the data types inside the SSIS flows are their own. I have the page up of what they are and what they map to.  I have even tried a data conversion flow in the middle to
no avail. I know this can't be that hard, as too many people are using it. I am missing something somewhere.
The Excel sheet is created in Office 365 in April 2021.

SQL Server is dev2019
visual studio is 2019 community.
SSIS was downloaded and added to Visual Studio in March 2021.

Comment: Change all your destination types to nvarchar(255) Load the data and then inspect it once it is in SQL Server. Does the date field show as `2021-04-25` (or whatever locale you work in) or is it an integer, like `44311`?

Comment: "destination types" must mean the types in the create statement in the "new" sql connection manager created in step 8. I did that and the error is "startofwork can not be inserted because no implicit conversion between dt_date and dt_wstr.  no joy

Comment: Snap a screenshot of your dataflow and then double click the connector line right before the Destination and get a picture of the Metadata page. Finally, right click the connector line before the Destination and add Data Viewer and get a screenshot of that data as well. That should help define your minimal, reproducible problem

Comment: thanks billinkc but I was trying that and ran into another problem and just decided to go back to my old way of loading these things.  I'm sure I'm just frustrated because it seems like this should be a no brainer given that all three products are Microsoft products.  Sorry to take your time and not have time to follow through myself

Comment: Believe it or not, the two biggest integration hardships I have found in my career are between Oracle and SQL Server (driver configuration + datetime difference) and Excel and SSIS (due to the interpreted nature of data types in Excel and the very rigid typing in SSIS)

Comment: I totally believe it after my experience.  I just find it very hard to believe that Microsoft couldn't spend a day or so thinking about how Excel stores time and what they need for SSIS.  Also SSIS data time datatype should be generic enough to be reinterpreted into whatever the destination would need.  Given the hundreds of thousands of hours of people like you and me trying to make it work it seems like a good investment. Anyway I am going to write a C# program and do it myself. it will be faster.  Well I think anyway

Comment: If you have future question about SSIS, be sure and come back. I enjoy the product, even if I no longer work with it on a daily basis

Comment: Maybe set this post as closed?

Comment: That's a great idea but every reason in "vote to close" renders a negative evaluation of the question.  I think the question is clear and follows all the guideline well enough not to have a negative connotation.  the answers are reasonably good suggestions as well it's just that as the OP I simply don't have time and it isn't worth it to me to continue fighting through it. I appreciate the answers, hopefully people appreciate that attempts to resolve an issue have to be balanced, continuously, against the value of that solution.  So I would be unhappy with a negative connotation to this

Comment: Peter Mortensen: I am not writing a book for publication.  I have found almost none of your edits to be helpful in understanding he question. In one case you changed  1/2 my bullet points to paragraphs (and leaving out a very important word in one of them).  In other cases you have made an edit that downgraded my question when the edit was cutting a word and adding the exact same word.  In almost no case have your edits left the question more understandable. It has made stackoverflow very unfriendly and a place I don't want to participate in unless I absolutely have too.